# Авторизация на сайте через другой сайт

Tags: php, битрикс, cms, авторизация

Доброго всем времени.

Есть задача. На сайте моем есть авторизация, нужно сделать чтобы при заполнении полей логин и пароль, пользователь нажал кнопку вход, и его перекинуло на другой сайт (в котором подставятся логи и пароль с моего сайта) и если он есть на сайте, то его сразу перекидывает в личный кабинет.

Пробовал курлом, но не могу понять, как сформировать запрос на авторизацию и перенаправить пользователя.

Подскажите что-нибудь дельное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<form action='http://domain.com/login.php' method='get'>
    Логин: <input type='text' name='login'><br/>
    Пароль: <input type='password' name='pass'><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>`
```

Может так?

Answer (score 1):

Как только написал, сам понял как сделать.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost.ru/index.html">
<h1>Login</h1><input class="class" type="text" value="Логин" maxlength="20" name="login"></br>
<h1>Pass</h1>
<input class="class" type="password" maxlength="20" name="pass"></br>
<input type="image" value="Войти">
</form>
```

Ответ правильный, только пост у меня.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="http://site.com/index.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="login"> <br>
<input type="text" name="password"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Войти"> </form>
```

Имена полей login и password посмотри в исходном коде на сайте где нужно авторизоваться, и замени их! Или если можешь просто оставь тут ссылку где хочешь авторизовывать пользователей я тебе напишу готовую форму.